# How can I display the parent directory of the current file in the modeline?

Tags: mode-line, directories

I would like to be able to see the location of the current file's parent directory, independent of the current buffer name.

Comment: Maybe using uniquify library is desired solution (see Gilles answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can configure the [mode line format](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html#Mode-Line-Format) as you wish. If you want to show the parent directory together with the buffer name (which is usually the file name, for a buffer that's visiting a file), modify [`mode-line-buffer-identification`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html#index-mode_002dline_002dbuffer_002didentification-1752); otherwise, add an entry to [`mode-line-format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html#index-mode_002dline_002dformat-1748). There isn't a [built-in construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html#g_t_0025_002dConstructs) for “parent directory of the current file”, so you'll need to [build that yourself](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data), for example with `:eval`. Here's an example that adds the directory name after the buffer name, and does nothing in buffers that aren't visiting files (including Dired); you may want to refine it with formatting.

```
(defun mode-line-buffer-file-parent-directory ()
  (when buffer-file-name
    (concat "[" (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))) "]")))
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
      (cons (car mode-line-buffer-identification) '((:eval (mode-line-buffer-file-parent-directory)))))
```

Another method would be to set a variable containing the text you want in `find-file-hooks`. I also show how you can set properties with the `:propertize` construct.

```
(defvar buffer-file-parent-directory nil
  "Parent directory of the current directory.
This variable is nil if the current buffer isn't visiting a file.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'buffer-file-parent-directory)
(put 'buffer-file-parent-directory 'permanent-local t)
(defconst mode-line-buffer-file-parent-directory
  '(:propertize (list buffer-file-parent-directory "/") face mode-line-buffer-id))
(defun set-buffer-file-parent-directory ()
  (when buffer-file-name
    (setq buffer-file-parent-directory
          (file-name-as-directory (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)))))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'set-buffer-file-parent-directory)
(let ((list mode-line-format))
  (while (not (eq (car list) 'mode-line-buffer-identification))
    (setq list (cdr list)))
  (setcdr list (cons (car list) (cdr list)))
  (setcar list 'mode-line-buffer-file-parent-directory))
```

If what you really wanted was to have the directory name in case you have multiple files with the same name in different directories, Emacs has this built in, with the [uniquify library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html#Uniquify). When there would be multiple buffers with the same name, this library causes the buffer name to look like `file.ext<foo>` and `file.ext<bar>` instead of `file.ext` and `file.ext<2>`. You can fine-tune the format by customizing `uniquify-buffer-name-style`.

```
(require 'uniquify)
```

Answer (score 10):

I assume you mean that you want to see the directory *instead of* the buffer name.

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              '(:eval default-directory))
```

Or if you want your home directory abbreviated to `~/` (instead of an absolute file name, from the root), then:

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              '(:eval (abbreviate-file-name default-directory)))
```

Or if you want only the parent directory name, as a single directory-component name, then:

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              '(:eval (file-name-nondirectory
                        (directory-file-name default-directory))))
```

Or if you do want to keep also the buffer name, as @Malabarba supposes, then:

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              (let ((orig  (car mode-line-buffer-identification)))
                `(:eval (cons (concat ,orig (abbreviate-file-name default-directory))
                              (cdr mode-line-buffer-identification)))))
```

The point is that you just need to use the value of [**`default-directory`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#File-Name-Expansion) (possibly simplified from an absolute name, if you want) in [**`mode-line-buffer-identification`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html#Mode-Line-Variables). You can set that variable to just the directory name, or you can set it to a value that keeps also the buffer name.

If what you ask is all you want, it is simple to configure the mode line to include the `default-directory`, however you want it to appear.  No need to load multiple libraries for this (which is what [`smart-mode-line`](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line) does).

Comment: Despite his wording, I *think* he meant "in addition to" not "instead". Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Malabarba: Maybe. If so, the difference is trivial - added.

Answer (score 7):

You install use
**[smart-mode-line](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line).**
It's configured to display the file path in the mode-line, whenever
that's relevant.

[image: dark theme]

Just install it, and then turn it on with `(sml/setup)`.

It also has a lot of features to make that display more concise. For
instance, *“~/.emacs.d/”* gets replaced with *“:ED:”* (and you can
configure further replacements).